# Override JpaRepository method or calling it's non overritten method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a JpaRepository and I'm trying to override its findById() method with a default call since all calls to findById() should receive an extra parameter.

I could just create a method with the extra parameter and replace the existing calls but if possible I want to avoid future developers mistakenly calling the original method, without this extra parameter. They won't need to provide it directly, hence the idea of overriding.

My approach to this was to create a new method in the repository with the extra parameter and override findById() method with a wrapped default method call.

```
// Creating the method with the extra parameter
Optional<Season> findByIdAndUnitId(Long id, Long unitId);

// Overriding and wrapping all the calls to the new default method
@Override
default Optional<Season> findById(Long id) {
   return findByIdAndUnitId(id, RequestContext.getCurrentUserValidating().getUnit());
}
```

The extra parameter I need to pass is a Long which is extracted from the RequestContext but getting this parameter could throw an Exception, so I need to catch it (also I'm not allowed to remove this exception).

```
@Override
default Optional<Season> findById(Long id) {
    try {
        return findByIdAndUnitId(id, RequestContext.getCurrentUserValidating().getUnit());
    } catch (DefaultException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What I want to do next is: If an exception gets raised I want to call the original method I'm overritting like so:

```
@Override
default Optional<Season> findById(Long id) {
    try {
        return findByIdAndUnitId(id, RequestContext.getCurrentUserValidating().getUnit());
    } catch (DefaultException e) {
        return super.findById(id)
    }
}
```

A few problems have arisen from this approach. The first one is that calling super from JpaRepository won't let me access findById method, since it is declared in one of its extended interfaces (CrudRepository), resulting in this error: `Unqualified super reference is not allowed in extension method`

I also did not have any luck trying the following:

```
return JpaRepository.super.findById(id); // Abstract method 'findById(ID)' cannot be accessed directly


return this.findById(id);   // Will call the same method, resulting in a possible infinite loop


return super.findById(id); // Unqualified super reference is not allowed in extension method
```

How can I call the original method inside the overritten one?

Edit:

Trying @talex suggestion:

```
return CrudRepository.super.findById(id); // Will produce 'org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository' is not an enclosing class
```

Answer (score 0):

Qualified `super` call looks like:

```
return CrudRepository.super.findById(id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Trying this approach produces "org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository' is not an enclosing class"